# Bluebird promisifyAll not creating entire set of Async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, coinbase-api

Maybe I'm not understanding the way `Promise.promisifyAll` works. I'm trying to promisify [coinbase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinbase) package.

Basically, the client's functions are promisified but the accounts returned by those functions don't appear to have the *Async* version: `[TypeError: acc.getTransactionsAsync is not a function]`.

I've tried passing `{multiArgs:true}` as options to `Promise.promisifyAll()` as suggested in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731331/wrap-node-multiparty-with-promisifyall-bluebird), but it didn't solve the problem. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Normal way of using the package (works):

```
var Client = require('coinbase').Client

var client = new Client({
  'apiKey': '<snip>',
  'apiSecret': '<snip>',
  'baseApiUri': 'https://api.sandbox.coinbase.com/v2/',
  'tokenUri': 'https://api.sandbox.coinbase.com/oauth/token'
});

//Callbacks
client.getAccounts({}, function(err, accounts) {
  accounts.forEach(function(acc) {
    acc.getTransactions(null, function(err, txns) {
      txns.forEach(function(txn) {
        console.log('txn: ' + txn.id);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Promisified version not working (`getTransactionsAsync` is undefined, but the `getAccountsAsync` returns the accounts correctly):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;

var client = new Client({
  'apiKey': '<snip>',
  'apiSecret': '<snip>',
  'baseApiUri': 'https://api.sandbox.coinbase.com/v2/',
  'tokenUri': 'https://api.sandbox.coinbase.com/oauth/token'
});

Promise.promisifyAll(client);

//Promises
client.getAccountsAsync({}) //Works perfectly, returns the accounts
.then(function(accounts) {
  return Promise.map(accounts, function(acc) {
    return acc.getTransactionsAsync(null); //This function call is throwing the TypeError
  });
})
.then(function(transactions) {
  console.log('Transactions:');
  transactions.forEach(function(tx) {
    console.log(tx);
  });
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

**EDIT:**

Looking through the package I want to promisify, I realized that the functions I'm trying to call are from the model objects returned by the package. I think `promisifyAll` only parses the client functions, and the models are not being processed. I'm just not that well versed on how the parsing is made :(

This is the index.js (module exported)

```
var Account       = require('./lib/model/Account.js'),
    Address       = require('./lib/model/Address.js'),
    Buy           = require('./lib/model/Buy.js'),
    Checkout      = require('./lib/model/Checkout.js'),
    Client        = require('./lib/Client.js'),
    Deposit       = require('./lib/model/Deposit.js'),
    Merchant      = require('./lib/model/Merchant.js'),
    Notification  = require('./lib/model/Notification.js'),
    Order         = require('./lib/model/Order.js'),
    PaymentMethod = require('./lib/model/PaymentMethod.js'),
    Sell          = require('./lib/model/Sell.js'),
    Transaction   = require('./lib/model/Transaction.js'),
    User          = require('./lib/model/User.js'),
    Withdrawal    = require('./lib/model/Withdrawal.js');

var model = {
  'Account'       : Account,
  'Address'       : Address,
  'Buy'           : Buy,
  'Checkout'      : Checkout,
  'Deposit'       : Deposit,
  'Merchant'      : Merchant,
  'Notification'  : Notification,
  'Order'         : Order,
  'PaymentMethod' : PaymentMethod,
  'Sell'          : Sell,
  'Transaction'   : Transaction,
  'User'          : User,
  'Withdrawal'    : Withdrawal
};

module.exports = {
  'Client' : Client,
  'model'  : model
};
```

**EDIT 2:**

The Client requires it's own model modules, so `Promise.promisifyAll` should as expected with the object's properties without having the previous edit interfering. At this point I think there might be no other option that making my own Promises for all functions I will need that don't live directly under the client.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating lots of `new Promise(...)` functions, but I can't find any other way to solve this problem so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think `promisifyAll` only parses the client functions, and the models are not being processed.

Not exactly. This has nothing to do with how `promisifyAll` is looking through the methods and properties. Rather, you are explicitly passing only the client methods to be promisified:

> ```
> var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
> var client = new Client(…);
> Promise.promisifyAll(client);
> ```

There's no link from `client` to the models. <s>Rather try to call `promisifyAll` on the whole module, not only the `Client` class:</s>

```
var Client = Promise.promisifyAll(require('coinbase')).Client;
```

or if that doesn't work, Call `promisifyAll` on both the `Client` class and the `models` collection of classes:

```
var coinbase = require('coinbase');
var Client = Promise.promisifyAll(coinbase.Client);
Promise.promisifyAll(coinbase.model);
```

Comment: That didn't work either, it was the original way I was making the call. After an answer/suggestion I changed it to this way, but he deleted his answer and I figure he was the one who downvoted my question. Inside the client there are requires for the models as properties, so they should be promisified (but aren't), see **EDIT 2**. I didn't wanted to copy&paste another big file, the question is too long already.

Comment: No, only because the `client.js` file requires some of the `modules/…` files doesn't mean they would get promisified. It will only promisify classes that are reachable as *properties* from the `Client` or `Client.prototype`.

Comment: Oh, right, `promisifyAll` doesn't consider to go deeper into `coinbase.models` because it's not a class (no uppercase name, etc).

Comment: "It doesn't consider to go deeper into `coinbase.models` because it's not a class", thanks a lot, now I know why. Actually I can't promisify the client definition, but I instantiated it and then promisified the models as well like this and it worked: `Promise.promisifyAll(client);
Promise.promisifyAll(coinbase.model);`

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of editing the question again I'm adding my temporary workaround (with a slightly different function call but that had the same problem of not having the `Async` function). This promisifies the model modules by it's own and I'll need to create them on demand whenever I need an promisified function on the non-promisified version of the models returned by the client.

It's not what I would like to do, since more memory allocation is needed for each model that I want to make a promisified function call. But I prefer this approach over creating new modules for grouping `new Promise(...)` functions.

If a better solution is suggested I'll still mark that as solved.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
var cbModel = require('coinbase').model;

var client = new Client({
  'apiKey': '<snip>',
  'apiSecret': '<snip>',
  'baseApiUri': 'https://api.sandbox.coinbase.com/v2/',
  'tokenUri': 'https://api.sandbox.coinbase.com/oauth/token'
});

Promise.promisifyAll(client);
Promise.promisifyAll(cbModel);

//Promises
client.getAccountAsync('primary')
.then(function(account) {
  account = new cbModel.Account(client, account);
  return account.getTransactionsAsync(null);
})
.then(function(transactions) {
  console.log('Transactions:');
  transactions.forEach(function(tx) {
    console.log(tx.id);
  });
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```